# Pseudocodigo funciones javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo que realizar un ejercicio para aprender a utilizar las funciones en javascript y el codigo esta en "pseudocodigo".

```
funcion calcular (salariobruto: enter, irpf: enter): real

algorismo

var 
   s,i,total: enter
   salario,dieta, real;

fvar

LLAMADA

falgorismo
```

El tema es que tengo que adivinar cual de las siguientes "llamadas" a la funcion es correcta y no acabo de ver ninguna de ellas:

1. salario:= salariobruto (s,i) + dietas;
2. total:= salariobruto (s,i);
3. salario:= salariobruto (total,irpf);
4. salario:= salariobruto (s,i);

Alguien me puede dar un poco de luz al tema?

Gracias

Comment: Te recomendaría que hagas una lectura a este sitio: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Funciones  , ahí trata el tema en general de como se hacen las funciones en javascript, checa, analiza, prueba los ejemplos que ahí vienen, y eso creo te podrá ayudar a aprender y entender como se realizan las funciones.

Comment: Me lo he leído y entiendo las funciones en codigo javascript, pero en el ejemplo que os he puesto no llego a entender cuales son las llamadas mas adecuadas.....

Answer (score 4):

Esta no es una pregunta como tal de programación y es más bien de una tarea.

> En JavaScript, Number es un tipo de datos numérico (double-precision 64-bit floating point format (IEEE 754)). En otros lenguajes de programación puede existir diferentes tipos numéricos, por ejemplo: Integers, Floats, Doubles, or Bignums.

Tomando en cuenta lo anterior tengo dos puntos importantes a destacar:

1. [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Numero) no tiene un tipo de dato para cada tipo de número por lo que no distingue entre un número real y un número entero (como se haría en C por ejemplo), tanto float como int, etc corresponden a [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number), lo mismo ocurre con TypeScript por ejemplo. Por lo que si conviertes dicha función a JavaScript, no obtendrías ningún tipo de error en cualquiera de las llamadas a excepción de la tercera por una razón que más adelante se explica.

> Number es un objeto primitivo envolvente que permite representar y manipular valores numéricos cómo 37 o -9.25.

2. En el pseudocódigo llamas a una función salariobruto, la cual no está definida y desde aquí ya podrías descartar que cualquier llamada a dicha función sea correcta.

Siguiendo la línea de pseudocódigo y asumiendo que salariobruto() refiere a calcular() se puede decir lo siguiente:

Calcular recibe dos ¿enteros? y retorna un real.

```
calcular(enter, enter) => real
```

`s` e `i` son enteros, `salario` y `dieta`, reales

```
s, i, total: enter
salario, dieta: real
```

Teniendo en cuenta los datos anteriores:

```
1. salario = calcular(s, i) + dieta [ok]
2. total = calcular(s, i) [no ok, total enter y función retorna real]
3. salario = calcular(total, irpf) [no ok, irpf no está definido]
4. salario = calcular(s, i) [ok]
```

Ahora bien, siguiendo la línea de JavaScript, la única llamada con error sería la tercera debido a que `irpf` no está definido (`irpf` solo existe dentro del scope de la función calcular). Esto lo puedes ver en el siguiente snippet (el orden fue modificado para evitar que la llamada número 3, rompa el código antes de llegar a la llamada 4):

```js
let s = 1,
    i = 2,
    salario = 1.5,
    dieta = 3.8;

const calcular = (salarioBruto, irpf) => salarioBruto * irpf; // El proceso es irrelevante
console.log('Valores iniciales');
console.log(`s: ${s}\ni: ${i}\nsalario: ${salario}\ndieta: ${dieta}`);
// Lamada 1
salario = calcular(s, i) + dieta;
console.log('salario = calcular(s, i) + dieta');
console.log(salario);

// Lamada 2
total = calcular(s, i);
console.log('total = calcular(s, i)');
console.log(total);

// Lamada 4
salario = calcular(s, i);
console.log('salario = calcular(s, i)');
console.log(salario);

// Lamada 3
salario = calcular(total, irpf);
console.log('salario = calcular(total, irpf)');
console.log('Error debido a irpf');
```